# how to use mvc-mini-profiler for database-first entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler, database-first

I am trying to use mvc-mini-profiler for db-first EF, but it is not working properly.

(note that I'm using objectcontext, not dbcontext)

Here is the list of stackoverflows I've tried:

- [Setup of mvc-mini-profiler for EF-db- first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843155/setup-of-mvc-mini-profiler-for-ef-db-first)
- [How to get MVC-mini-profiler working on EF 4.1 Database First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212926/how-to-get-mvc-mini-profiler-working-on-ef-4-1-database-first)

versions:

- Entity Framework: 4.3.1
- MiniProfiler: 2.0.2
- MiniProfiler.ef: 2.0.3

This is how I setup miniprofiler:

1. I've added the following stuff in Global.asax

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(
   {
       MiniProfiler.Start();   
   }

   protected void Application_EndRequest()
   {
       MiniProfiler.Stop();
   }

   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       ...

       MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42();
   }
   ```
2. Then configure an objectcontext,

   ```
   var entityConnection = new EntityConnection(ConnectionString);
   var profiledDbConnection = new EFProfiledDbConnection(entityConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
   var context = profiledDbConnection.CreateObjectContext<MyContext>();
   var list = context.MyEntities.ToList();
   ```

If I execute this, the following exception occurs when running "context.MyEntities.ToList()"

[System.Data.EntityCommandCompliationException]

the message in the inner exception says:
EntityClient cannot be used to create a command definition from a store command tree.

Have I configured wrong? Any help?

thanks,

Comment: You may probably missed this post: [Using Mini-Profilier with EF 4.3 & MVC 4 without creating the database][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9539946/1437962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MiniProfiler and database first Entity Framework and it does work well.  You may need to turn off the database initialization strategy inside of your database context as per this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9762989/325727

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    static EmployeeContext() { Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeContext>(null); }    
    public IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } 
}
```

The parameter `null` turns off database initialization by making sure that there is no initializer available.

Comment: thanks, but i am using ObjectContext rather than DbContext. It seems that Database.SetInitializer works only for DbContext.